# Cuda, device, expression must have integral or enum type

Tags: c++, casting, cuda

The following error is thrown at the two assignments of `targets` in the if statement.

```
error: expression must have integral or enum type
```

All the variables in the operation are or return floating values as they are declared as such. Yet it doesn't like the conversion to integers. Why is this? Are there differences between different kinds of floats or integers?

```
__global__
void generateTargets(int* targets, int targetAmount, float radius, float angleStep){
   float i = blockIdx.x;
   if(i < targetAmount){ // Ensure it stays in range
       // Access the 1d array representation of the 2d array [MAX_TARGETS][2]
       targets[i + MAX_TARGETS*0] = __float2int_rd(radius*__cosf(i*angleStep)); // X value
       targets[i + MAX_TARGETS*1] = __float2int_rd(radius*__sinf(i*angleStep)); // Y value
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `targets[i + MAX_TARGETS*0]` and `targets[i + MAX_TARGETS*1]` you are using `i` which is a `float`.  That makes the entire expression to calculate the array index a `float`.  You can't do this though as array indexes must be an integer type (there is no element 4.5).

If you want to keep `i` a `float` you will need to cast/convert it to an `integer type or cast/convert the result of the expression to an integer type.

Comment: I see, what would be best, declare it as an int and cast it to a float on the right hand side where it is used or have it be declared as a float and cast it to an integer? Which conversion is fastest?

Comment: @JohanSundman Since `angleStep` is a `float` you can make `i` an `int` and it will be automatically converted to a float for you.  That is probably the fastest and easiest solution.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not sure this is a good idea (depending on what the OP wants to a mathematical point of view), `radius*__cosf(i*angleStep)` value will be changed as `i` fractional part will be truncated.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois I guess that really depends on what `blockIdx.x` is.  I assumed it was an integer type to begin with and if that is the case then there wont be a fractional part.  I'll as the OP

Comment: @JohanSundman What is `blockIdx` and what is the type of `x` in `blockIdx.x`?

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois The `blockIdx.x` is an integer, I think. It doesn't have any fractional part to it at least.  So the answer was great. Thanks for the concern though.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's an integer value and I assume the type is an integer too. It should be in the cuda documentation but I think it's safe to say it's an integer.

Comment: Then if it's an integer ok! Indeed you just have to replace your `float i = blockIdx.x;` by `int i = blockIdx.x;`, you will have a single type conversion this way (conversions from/to integer/floating-point are costly)

Comment: These CUDA kernel built-in variables are of integral type (technically `uint` for `blockIdx.x`) and are documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#built-in-variables).